# Reading all files in a directory and showing their content on a web page using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Background:**

I have a directory on my server where I store the logs. I'm trying to display all the files in there on a single webpage in a list, with the contents of the latest log at the bottom. These log files are created using code elsewhere (out of scope of this question), and a new log could be inserted into the directory at random intervals, whenever that code runs. I would have this webpage open while I run that code to see the log contents of all files created since the web page was opened.

**Problem:**

At the moment I have a single file that I am able to read from successfully, and if I manually edit it, the new contents are reflected onto my web page. But how do I make an AJAX call that iterates over all files in the directory and lists their contents in an "oldest file first" order?

**Code:**

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <Body>
    
    <p><center>Current Transaction(s):</center></p> 
    <ul>
        <li id="transactioninfo">Loading Transaction Information...</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    function getLogs() {
    
    var url = 'http://<myurl>/logs/1.log'; //instead of this I want the whole directory's file's contents
    
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data) {
    
           $("#transactioninfo").html(data)
        },
    
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
    
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        setTimeout(function(){getLogs();}, 2000);
        setInterval(function(){getLogs();}, 2000);
    
    });
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: You would have to do this in your backend... I don't think this will be possible in a static webpage

Comment: @Milney What would be the way to pass a variable from python to this?

Comment: That is kind of beyond the scope of a question on StackOverflow... Please try using google for 'python website'... there are many tutorials you can follow. For example: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972

Comment: Okay, but the method would be to pass data from a script to this ajax call, right?

Comment: Well... you would probably do the ajax call to a url which points to your python code... the python code would then enumerate the directory and pass the results back in response to the call as the ajax response

Comment: Seriously just read a tutorial and you will understand

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without having server response with list of server files.
This totally depends on your server.